# Meteor: inserting in collection using for loop only inserts first loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, meteor

I am just learning meteor (well development in general) and I am trying to insert into a collection using a simple for loop on server side

```
getFriendsData: function() {   
    for (i=0; i<10; i+=1){
        console.log (i)
        Friendlist.insert({
            name: "test"+i,
            "userid": Meteor.user()._id
        })
    }
```

For some reason this only gives me one result (the first one test0). The log is showing that the entire loop is being run but there is only one insert. Could someone explain what is happening here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a unique index on `userid` in the Friendlist collection? It looks like you're inserting the same `userid` on every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems ok, how do you assert that it's not doing what it's supposed to ?

Here is a rewrite of your code that is doing fine when tested on my machine :

lib/collections/friendlist.js :

```
Friendlist=new Meteor.Collection("friendlist");
```

server/server.js :

```
Meteor.methods({
  getFriendsData:function(){
    if(!this.userId){
      throw new Meteor.Error(500,"Must be signed in to get friends data !");
    }
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
      console.log(i);
      Friendlist.insert({
        name:"test"+i,
        userId:this.userId
      });
    }
    Friendlist.find().forEach(function(name){
      console.log(friend.name);
    });
  }
});

Meteor.startup(function(){
  // for testing purpose : always reset data on startup
  Friendlist.remove({});
});
```

Then you `Meteor.call("getFriendsData");` in your browser console and in your server console you see the 10 documents of `Friendlist` being printed as they should.

If you didn't remove the `autopublish` package, you can type `Friendlist.find().fetch()` in your browser console to check that your 10 documents have been correctly inserted.

If it still doesn't work, show more of your code that might have side effects.

Comment: Copy pasting your code gives an Error invoking Method 'getFriendsData': Internal server error [500]. I just activate it with a button 
    "click .addfriend": function(){

        Meteor.call("getFriendsData") }

Comment: Are you clicking the button while a user is currently logged in ? Because apparently your method stores userIds based on the current logged in user, so this is obviously not going to work if not connected.

Comment: To setup user login in minutes, `meteor add accounts-password` `meteor add accounts-ui` and invoke `{{> loginButtons}}` somewhere in your app template.